# How to modify the Nicks Pallet (in Substrate) to set the nickname via a transfer of currency to another account, instead of using reserve currency?

Tags: rust, substrate

In the Nicks Pallet, an account can set a nickname for itself via reserve currency. I would like to modify this functionality to instead require a fee to be paid to another specific account (for now I would just like to send the fee to the Alice account) in order to set a nickname.

This seems like it should be a fairly simply modification, but as I am new to Substrate and Rust this is not quite as straightforward as I would have thought. I've already forked the Nicks Pallet, but simply cannot quite figure out how to proceed from here.

I am working in a locally cloned version of [substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the high level changes you would need to make:

1. Introduce a new [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) to your pallet's configuration `Trait`:

```rust
pub trait Trait: frame_system::Trait {
    // -- snip --
    // This is a new type that allows the runtime to configure where the payment should go.
    type PaymentReceiver: Get<Self::AccountId>;
}
```

2. Update `set_name` function to use a different `Currency` function. In this case we want to `transfer` instead of `reserve`:

```rust
// New import needed
use frame_support::traits::ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive;
```

```rust
fn set_name(origin, name: Vec<u8>) {
    let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    ensure!(name.len() >= T::MinLength::get(), Error::<T>::TooShort);
    ensure!(name.len() <= T::MaxLength::get(), Error::<T>::TooLong);

    let deposit = if let Some((_, deposit)) = <NameOf<T>>::get(&sender) {
        Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::NameChanged(sender.clone()));
        deposit
    } else {
        let deposit = T::ReservationFee::get();
        // The only change is made here...
        T::Currency::transfer(&sender, &T::PaymentReceiver::get(), deposit.clone(), KeepAlive)?;
        Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::NameSet(sender.clone()));
        deposit
    };

    <NameOf<T>>::insert(&sender, (name, deposit));
}
```

3. Comment out the parts of the code where we would `unreserve` or `slash_reserved`, since these behaviors do not apply with this new logic.

`fn clear_name`

```rust
// let _ = T::Currency::unreserve(&sender, deposit.clone());
```

`fn kill_name`

```
// T::Slashed::on_unbalanced(T::Currency::slash_reserved(&target, deposit.clone()).0);
```

4. Once you have made these changes, your pallet should compile just fine:

```sh
substrate git:(master) ✗ cargo build -p pallet-nicks
   Compiling pallet-nicks v2.0.0-rc6 (/Users/shawntabrizi/Documents/GitHub/substrate/frame/nicks)
   Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.48s
```

5. To actually use these changes in your runtime, you will need to configure it with this new `PaymentReceiver` trait:

```rust
// Here we define the value of the receiver
// `//Alice` -> `5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY`
// -> `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`
// Using: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/

ord_parameter_types! {
    pub const PaymentReceiverValue: AccountId = AccountId::from(
        hex_literal::hex!("d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d")
    );
}
```

> You may need to introduce the [`hex_literal`](https://docs.rs/hex-literal/0.3.1/hex_literal/) crate into your runtime.

And we use this value in our trait implementation:

```
impl pallet_nicks::Trait for Runtime {
    // -- snip --
    type PaymentReceiver: PaymentReceiverValue;
}
```

And that is it! Let me know if this helps.

Comment: After going to bed really frustrated with this, I just woke up to your very detailed answer. Before even trying this, I have to say I am both humbled and appreciative that you took the time to work this out for me in such detail. This may be just the type of thing I need, as someone just starting out in Substrate and Rust, to gain a deeper understanding of the workings of Substrate, and what is required to make modifications to its functionality. Thank you so much! I will try this out today, and will report back with the results.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks once again for such a detailed answer!